# Project update via TextMate (like Espresso)

Tags: ftp, textmate, macrabbit-espresso

I am thoroughly in love with [TextMate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextMate).  I program everything in it, including [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) for my daily job.  However, I have a license for [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/), and I was looking at it recently and discovered that there is a "Publish" section that I knew about before, but I didn't know that it could compare my FTP directory with my local directory and publish only the changed files.

Over the past week I've been finding myself using Espresso just for that functionality. However, I was hoping there was a way to get this functionality inside TextMate. I know that you could use an AppleScript script with Cyberduck (my FTP client) to upload a file when it changes, but I have never got that working and it also doesn't include the ability to merge files like Espresso does.

Am I plumb out of luck? Am I stuck using two different programs for the forseeable future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to set up a simple `rsync` command in a bundle in TextMate that will use environment variables from your project to synchronise.

See *[Using rsync to enable the project drawer in TextMate while working on a remote server](https://web.archive.org/web/20080820132436/http://enure.net/post/article/using-rsync-to-enable-the-project-drawer-in-textmate-while-working-on-a-remote-server)* for an example.